# jquery sortable make user able to drag elements after `n` seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable to sort the list of images. Currently, the user can just simply tap and move images to sort them. However, I want to have it work a bit differently. I want that the user should tap and hold the image (which are inside the `<li>` tags here) for 2 seconds which would then activate the image with a border around it and only then the user can drag the images for sorting. Is this possible?

HTML

```
<ul id="sortable" class="reorder-gallery mt-5">
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="1" data-name="1.png">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="2" data-name="2.png">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="3" data-name="3.png">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="4" data-name="4.png">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  axis: 'x,y',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance:'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) {
    $("#sortable").sortable( "option", "distance", 5 );
    var item_order = new Array();
    $('.reorder-gallery li').each(function() {
        item_order.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processes/sort.php",
        data: 'order='+item_order,
        cache: false,
      success: function(data){}
    });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`delay` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-delay) in jQuery UI sortable which may help:

> Time in milliseconds to define when the sorting should start. Adding a delay helps preventing unwanted drags when clicking on an element.

Please note that the option is deprecated and only available in jQuery UI versions before `1.12`.

Additionally helper needs to be enabled (`helper: 'clone'`) and [styled](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#theming) (`#sortable .ui-sortable-helper`).

*P.S.* Sadly I did not find the way to change styling when delay time has passed.

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  delay: 1000, // wait for 1 second before dragging
  helper: "clone", // allows styling of element when dragging
  axis: 'x,y',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance:'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) {
    $("#sortable").sortable( "option", "distance", 5 );
    var item_order = new Array();
    $('.reorder-gallery li').each(function() {
        item_order.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processes/sort.php",
        data: 'order='+item_order,
        cache: false,
      success: function(data){}
    });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
#sortable .ui-sortable-helper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable" class="reorder-gallery mt-5">
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="1" data-name="1.png">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="2" data-name="2.png">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="3" data-name="3.png">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default mediaSort" id="4" data-name="4.png">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
```